Relay not turning on a Motor
I am new to electronics. I want to reverse a motor using 2 relays but when i turn on the switch nothing changes.


Please create a circuit diagram showing how you connected the various components. Also, do your relays click when they should?

Yes they work. and here is the image of the circuit

Show the controlling circuit - how are the relay coils wired?  Does your motor work when connected directly to the battery?

You need to connect the motor to the two centre connections (of each set of three) so the schematic ends up like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
To drive the motor one way or the other, energize just one of the two relays.
If neither relay (or both) are energized then the motor will not be driven.

The markings are potentially (as it were) a bit confusing. The COMMON is in the MIDDLE of each grouping. The Normally Closed is on one side, and Normally Open on the other. Imagine that line (on the PCB silk screen, which you have just deleted, sadly) pivoting near the terminal strip to touch the other side when the relay is energized.
Red = energized
Green = de-energized

